# A reusable way to get the directory of the current user-defined package in Python?

Tags: python

For the following directory structure, I would like to write logs into `my_package/logs` folder via `log_manager.py`.

```
my_package/
    my_package/
        __init__.py
        main.py
        log_manager.py
        logs/
    setup.py
```

I wanted to ensure that executing entry points from any directory in my system can consistently write logs to `my_package/logs`.
One approach is to assume the directory structure and get the parent directory of `log_manager.py` to infer `logs/`:

```
package_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, '..')))
log_dir = os.path.join(package_dir, 'logs')
```

However, if in the future, I wanted to add another directory `plots` (shown below), I need to once again retrieve my package directory using the similar ways, which is repetitive.

```
my_package/
    my_package/
        __init__.py
        main.py
        log_manager.py
        logs/
        plots/
    setup.py
```

Therefore, I wanted to find reusable ways to locate the package directory. To do so, I can define a function in `log_manager.py`, but not sure if this is the best way to do this? This function seems to be a very common feature and I was expecting simpler ways.

```
def get_package_dir():
    package_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, '..')))
    return package_dir
```

Comment: Can you `import my_package` and make everything relative to `my_package.__file__`?

Comment: Couldn't `log_manager.py` just assume that `/logs` was a subdirectory of whatever directory it is in (found via its own `__file__` variable)? This wouldn't be affect by adding other subdirectories at the same level.

Comment: @mgilson I wanted to get the dir of `/logs` within the same package, instead of calling the package from the outside.

Comment: @martineau Yes, I can! I just wanted to know if there are simpler ways, and I wanted to find a reusable solution to find the package directory, if there is any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setuptools' [pkg_resources](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PkgResources) module provide helpers method to locate absolute path to your modules.

```
from pkg_resources import resource_filename as resource

package_dir = resource('my-package', 'log_manager.py')
log_dir = os.path.join(package_dir, 'logs')
```

Even though, I don't think it's a good practice to write logs in a modules directory.

Comment: @Jiang Xiang: How is hardcoding resource names reusable? Seems like using something like `__file__` would more generic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for, but can't you just place methods in log_manager.py that writes the logs into logs/ and import log_manager from anywhere in your project? You could use a separate plot_manager.py to dump plots into plots/.

Comment: Yes, this will work. But I am looking for reusable ways to locate the package. Please see my edit.